# How do you match a MVC model class to existing database table and schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Visual Studio 2012, MVC 4, and Razor (CSHTML). I created Person.Person table in a test database. I wanted to have my model PersonModels.cs use this table so I created the following 2 classes.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
    public string PersonType { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public int EmailPromotion { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(DataType = "string")]
    public string AdditionalContactInfo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(DataType = "string")]
    public string Demographics { get; set; }
    public string rowguid { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> person { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that it would pick the Person.Person table since the class name was Person even though I had not included the schema. However, upon running the application and doing an insert I checked the Person.Person table but the row wasn't there. It created dbo.People table and inserted the row there! I double checked because I thought I might be drunk but I did not write People anywhere!

I read about reverse poco but I'd like to understand how this works more than making it work.

**Edit: It worked! Please find the code I used attached:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace client_site.Models
{
    [Table("Person", Schema = "Person")]
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class DefaultConnectionX : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestModel> test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF automatically pluralizes many kinds of table names... Person is pluralized as People.  You can disable this by removing the Pluralization convention, or you can just specify the tablename in an attribute or in fluent configuration.  See Raimond's response for the reason it didn't use the Person schema.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch , lets take `dbo` is default schema  , for example,  `public DbSet<Person> persons { get; set; }` what does `persons` means ? pluralized table name or property name right ?

Comment: @stom - "persons" is just the name of the variable, it's whatever you call it.  It has nothing to do with the table name.  The table name will be derived from the entitiy name (Person).

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch , ok so you mean entity framework automatically provides a table name based on my class name ? In [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model) article in `MSDN` author used  `public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }` and [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) at bottom i can see table name as Movies , so is it based on variable or entity framework automatically did it ?

Comment: @stom - yes, EF automatically pluralizes the class name.  You can disable that, but that's the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbo is the default database schema. If you want to create the table in the people schema you have to add an attribute

[Table("Person", Schema = "Person")]